# Java Terminal/CMD Interaction

Tags: java, terminal, cmd

What I'm trying to do is make my own java program interact with pianobarfly (https://github.com/nega0/pianobarfly) via command line / terminal. At this point I can seemingly start the application, however only the first line is printed out via java. It does not seem to be recognizing the lines that follow. How would I go about this?

```
    import java.io.*;

class mainA
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
       try {
           Process p = new ProcessBuilder("/Users/sbuck1994/Desktop/pianobarfly-master/pianobarfly").start();
           BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
           BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
           String resultLine = input.readLine();

           while (resultLine != null) {
             System.out.println(resultLine);
             resultLine = input.readLine();
           }

           int exitVal = p.waitFor();
           System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);

       } catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e.toString());
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

This results in:

```
Welcome to pianobarfly (2012.09.07-dev)! Press ? for a list of commands.
```

When I think it should print something like this:

```
Welcome to pianobarfly (2012.09.07-dev)! Press ? for a list of commands.
[?] Email:
```

And here is what it looks like when using terminal:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ8vp.png

Answer (score 0):

You might need to also process the error stream. See [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for more info.